# Customized Table DDL from dbms_metadata.get_ddl

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, rdbms, database-administration

I want `DDL`s of Tables so that I can put it to the database server using `UTL` Package in Oracle.

The problem is : When we

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','Table_name','Schema_Name') 
  from dual;
```

I get an output which contains `CLOB` before `CREATE`. Like

```
"(CLOB) 
  CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA"."TABLE_NAME" 
   (TABLE_COLUMNS.....) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "INTF_DATA01" ;"
```

What I want is the above `DDL` without `CLOB` and without the parameters such as `SEGMENT CREATION`, `PCTFREE` ... ETC..

Would be glad to get advise.

Comment: The `(CLOB)` looks like something your client might be adding to show the result is, well, a `CLOB`. Which client are you using, and can you run this from SQL*Plus or something instead to see if it's still shown?

Comment: You could always use substring if there's no other solution.

Answer (score 7):

We can use the DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM method to control what clauses are included in the generated DDL.

For instance to exclude SEGMENT stuff you would execute this

```
exec dbms_metadata.set_transform_param
   (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES',false);
```

before you execute your `get_ddl()` call.

The package documentation lists all the available Trandformation parameters. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1000135).

---

I think Alex is right, and the "(CLOB)"  at the front is something your client is prepending to the output.  But it were real and not an artefact getting rid of it would be a simple string manipulation:

```
substr(your_string, 7)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. *Please use below logic: it is working for me*

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ddl_ty AS OBJECT (   object_name
VARCHAR2(30),   object_type VARCHAR2(30),   orig_schema
VARCHAR2(30),   orig_ddl    CLOB ) / CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE
ddl_ty_tb AS TABLE OF ddl_ty /

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_ddl (input_values
SYS_REFCURSOR) RETURN ddl_ty_tb PIPELINED IS

PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

-- variables to be passed in by sys_refcursor */ object_name  VARCHAR2(30); object_type  VARCHAR2(30); orig_schema VARCHAR2(30);


-- setup output record of TYPE tableddl_ty out_rec ddl_ty := ddl_ty(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

/* setup handles to be used for setup and fetching metadata
information handles are used to keep track of the different objects
(DDL) we will be referencing in the PL/SQL code */ hOpenOrig  
NUMBER; hModifyOrig NUMBER; hTransDDL   NUMBER; dmsf       
PLS_INTEGER; Orig_ddl  CLOB; ret        NUMBER; BEGIN   /* Strip off
Attributes not concerned with in DDL. If you are concerned with
     TABLESPACE, STORAGE, or SEGMENT information just comment out these few lines. */   dmsf := dbms_metadata.session_transform;  
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dmsf, 'TABLESPACE', FALSE);  
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dmsf, 'STORAGE', FALSE);  
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dmsf, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES',
FALSE);   dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dmsf, 'PRETTY', TRUE);  
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dmsf, 'SQLTERMINATOR', TRUE);

  -- Loop through each of the rows passed in by the reference cursor
LOOP
    /* Fetch the input cursor into PL/SQL variables */
    FETCH input_values INTO object_name, orig_schema, object_type;
    EXIT WHEN input_values%NOTFOUND;

    hOpenOrig := dbms_metadata.open(object_type);
    dbms_metadata.set_filter(hOpenOrig,'NAME',object_name);
    dbms_metadata.set_filter(hOpenOrig,'SCHEMA',orig_schema);

    hModifyOrig := dbms_metadata.add_transform(hOpenOrig,'MODIFY');
    dbms_metadata.set_remap_param(hModifyOrig,'REMAP_SCHEMA',orig_schema,null);

    -- This states to created DDL instead of XML to be compared
    hTransDDL := dbms_metadata.add_transform(hOpenOrig ,'DDL');

    Orig_ddl := dbms_metadata.fetch_clob(hOpenOrig);

      out_rec.object_name := object_name;
      out_rec.object_type := object_type;
      out_rec.orig_schema := orig_schema;
      out_rec.orig_ddl := Orig_ddl;
      PIPE ROW(out_rec);

    -- Cleanup and release the handles
    dbms_metadata.close(hOpenOrig);

  END LOOP;   RETURN; END get_object_ddl; / SELECT *   FROM
TABLE(get_object_ddl(CURSOR (SELECT object_name, owner, object_type
                               FROM dba_objects
                              WHERE owner = 'EMP'
                                    AND object_type IN
                                    ('VIEW',
                                         'TABLE',
                                         'TYPE',
                                         'PACKAGE',
                                         'PROCEDURE',
                                         'FUNCTION',
                                         'SEQUENCE'))));
```

---

1. List item

Comment: Care to explain a bit ? This wall of code is not particularly fun to read.

Answer (score 1):

`get_ddl` returns a CLOB.  Cast it to a character type and your library won't add the (CLOB).

```
select to_char(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','Table_name','Schema_Name'))
    from dual;
```